# Communication between containers in docker (docker-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, network-programming

I am currently setting up a buildkite build pipeline which runs an api in one docker container and an application in another docker container alongside it while running Cypress tests (which are also running within the second container).

I use the following docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  testing-image:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./deploy/Dockerfile-cypress
    image: cypress-testing
  cypress:
    image: cypress-testing
    ipc: host
    depends_on:
      - api
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "63790:6379"
  api:
    build:
      context: ../api/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: api
    command: /env/development/command.sh
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
```

The application runs in the cypress container when started by buildkite. It then starts the cypress tests and some of them pass. However, any test that requires communication with the API fails because the cypress container is unable to see localhost within the API container. I am able to enter the API container using a terminal and have verified that it is working perfectly internally using cURL.

I have tried various URLs within the cypress container to try to reach the API, which is available on port 8080 within the API container, including `api://api:8080` and `http://api:8080` but none of them have been able to see the API.

Does anybody know what could be going on here?

Comment: make link between cypress and api container and check all containers are in same network. after making link between cypress and api try to test curl command for api from cypress container

Comment: @BhagyashriMachale Thanks for the reply. I have created a link and tried again, but unfortunately it hasn't fixed anything. Using curl within the cypress container for `http://api:8080` gives `curl: (7) Failed to connect to api port 8080: Connection refused` while `api://api:8080` fails because curl doesnt support `api://`.

How would I check that all containers are within the same network? The services within them are accessible on their respective localhosts and both their containers are running side-by-side on the same server.

Comment: first did you expose `api` container on `8080` port for other services to connect.I could not see port mapping in docker-compose file. Use docker network inspect command for network

Comment: @BhagyashriMachale I have now added a ports section under api with "8080:8080", but unfortunately that hasn't fixed it. I have also used docker network inspect with the network that is created and in the "Containers" section there are 4 containers - api, redis, cypress and db.

Comment: Can you post Dockerfile for your api?

Comment: @Carlos As it was written by the company I work for I probably can't post it in its entirety here, but I can summarise everything that it does:

The ubuntu:18.04 image is used. We then install all apt dependencies followed by pip dependencies. We then copy the required folders for the api to run into the container. Lastly we configure uwsgi by assigning an ini file.

Comment: In case anyone is interested all the tests described here:

https://maximorlov.com/4-reasons-why-your-docker-containers-cant-talk-to-each-other/

Were successful including the pinging between the cypress and api containers using container ids and pinging the api container from the cypress one by IP address. As these identifiers aren't stable every time the testing runs however, I would not be unable to use them to resolve my issues.

Comment: Are you able to do a curl to http://localhost:8080 from within the api container?

Comment: Also after adding the port mapping to your api are you able to access it from your host via the browser or postman?

Comment: @Carlos Yes, when I do that it displays the response I expect from an empty API query.

Comment: @Carlos I am unable to install postman or run a browser as it is on our build server. However, if I do curl localhost:8080 directly on the build server instead of within the container the API is running in it still works so the port mapping seems to be working.

Comment: Can you try removing all the links sections from all your services?

Comment: By the way you should really be using networks instead, if you want to isolate communication between services.

Comment: @Carlos thanks for all your advice. I discovered that when my API is running in development mode, as it is during the tests, it doesn't allow itself to be addressed as any host name other than localhost, which is why localhost:8080 was working but api:8080 wasn't. I found this because of an error it started showing eventually when running curl in the cypress container after I made some of the suggested changes above. I have now fixed this and everything is working as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.